# probability that a variable is ONE OF the top k out of n when ordered

Tags: probability, random-variable, ranking, order-statistics

Suppose ($h_1,h_2,...,h_n$) is an $n\times 1$ vector.

Let $h_i=g_iX_i$, where $g_i$ is a non-random variable which can vary across $i$ and $X_i$ is a random variable with Pareto Type I distribution.

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
{\alpha x_m^\alpha \over x^{\alpha +1}},  & \text{if $x\ge x_m$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x\lt x_m$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

What is the probability, as a function of $g$'s, that any given $h_i$ will be among the top $k$ largest of the $n$ $h$'s?

Comment: The answer for the case where all the $g_j, j\ne i,$ are equal to each other appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5850. The general case is much, much messier. Writing down a formula would be unilluminating and not provide an effective computational method. Thus, you might benefit from refocusing this question on whatever the underlying problem is so that your readers could have some guidance concerning how to approximate the answer.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge... order statistics for the Pareto distribution are easily obtained with monotonic transformations from the exponential distribution. The $g$_is make these distributions non-identical, which makes the answer a very, very complicated direct integral.

Comment: The setting of this problem is:  Each player $i$ chooses an effort level, $g_i$ which is subject to Pareto Type I distributed shocks, $X_i$, resulting in outcome $h_i=g_iX_i$.  Outcomes of the players are ranked. What is the probability that player %i%'s outcome will be ranked among the top %k%?  This probability, as a function of the effort levels, $g$'s, is needed to derive FOCs for optimal effort, $g$*. Thanks.  @whuber

Comment: I will check out the transformations you suggested. The order statistics probabilities I come across normally are, for example, probability density of the $k$th order statistics. Whereas in this case, it is the probability that a particular individual's observation being ranked one of the top $k$. Just wondering if this is considered order statistics as well. Thanks. @AdamO